# Weird issue in route drawing in Android google MAP

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-directions-api

In one of my android app I have to draw a route between two points(say A & B). I am drawing the route using Google Direction API+Google Parser+Route overlay class. Everything is working perfect but sometimes a very strange route is drawn that does not make any sense. Please see the below image of the route drawn

[image]

You can see a very strange route is drawn in this case.

Any idea or help in this regards will be highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: It seems to be that the algorythm fills all the possible routes to point B at once, I mean that it draws every possible way of getting to that point? To prove this hypothesis, select point B to be a big far (to give it more possibilities).